# Demagnetisation by throwing a magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science, classical-electrodynamics

I tried to answer this question in a book about electrodynamics:

> How to demagnetise a permanent magnet, ie. described by $ D_T$ change into described by (0,0)

[image]

I figured out about heating it up and magnetizing back and forth, but in the answer section there was one more solution:

> Drop the magnet on something hard

How does this method work?

Comment: I like your solution.  (Text books often have mistakes.)

Answer (score 2):

Ferromagnetic materials contain [magnetic domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain) within which the electrons spins are aligned to give a net magnetic moment. Bulk magnetisation is done by changing the alignment within the domains so they all align in the same direction and their magnetic fields all reinforce.

Anything that puts energy into the crystal lattice can randomise the alignments again and destroy the bulk magnetisation. Heating is one way to add energy to the lattice, but mechanical shock can also do it. However it's hard to get much energy in using mechanical shock so only low coercivity magnets are likely to be affected. Allegedly (I have never done the experiment) pure iron is quite easily demagnetised by shock but high coercivity magnets like [neodymium magnets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neodymium_magnet) are unaffected.

Comment: Do you think it is extremely hard to calculate energy of throw needed for demagnetization? Or maybe just very hard? What coefficients would I need to know?